# Excel if function with multiple conditions BUT just one must be fullfiled

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have data from over 100 countries in a table. Now I want to categorize those countries in 3 cathegories. (0,1,2). So I have a list 1 and 2. All other countries should receive the country code "0". If I use now the function "if" to check if the first country is in list 1 (return 1) or else return 0. I receive 10 times a 0(for each country), because there are 10 countries in list 1. But of course I just need to receive the one single country code that belongs to it. (If it matches only one country in the list 1 => TRUE)

Do I need an other function, or what do I need to change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You formula need to compare with both list1 and list2. Provide some sample data and expected output. Also put here your current formula.

Answer (score 0):

> if" to check if the first country is in list ..

you can use `=IF(COUNTIF(urData,urData)>0,1,0)`

is this what u r looking for ?